# Some software for IIS/.NET similar to JAWR (consolidate and minify Javascript)

Tags: javascript, optimization, jawr

Is there any software package/library that will produce a consolidated, minified JavaScript file for a production environment, while leaving the original files/references as-is in a development environment (so developers can work independently)?

[JAWR does this](https://jawr.dev.java.net/) (and more) for a Java/Groovy environment, but I haven't seen anything like it for the Microsoft .NET/IIS7 stack.  Any pointers would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: You might try http://runtimepageoptimizer.com/

Answer (score 1):

We use [YUICompressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minify our Javascript (and CSS) and it works well.

However, we've had to write our own HttpHandler to decide whether to minify or not on the fly, depending on a config setting (but it could equally be on whether it was a DEBUG or RELEASE build).

In fact, we cache the file once minified (or not), so we don't have to do the same process on every request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a good way to automatically compress and combine css & js files here are some options:

- [Xpedite](http://xpedite.codeplex.com/) Not bad: has one big disadantage: you can't combine files (js/css) that are included in usercontrols with the files in your page.
- [Shinkansen](http://shinkansen.codeplex.com/), I don't have a lot of experience with it, but I know it has a lot of configuration options.
- The [ClientDependency Framework](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) was originally written for [Umbraco](http://umbraco.com). Now there is a package available via NuGet for both WebForms and MVC. It works really well and this is my favorite.